# cakephp deleteAll doesn't delete matched data

Tags: cakephp

everyone. I have a trouble with deleteAll().
I want to delete all matched data. So I googled and found deleteAll().
I understood how to use deleteAll() as

```
$this->Tablename->deleteAll(condition)
```

cakephp 3.x

```
$result = $this->table->deleteAll(['id' => 1]);
var_dump($result);
```

I checked deleted count. That show matched record count I expected, that's why I think it's not problem.
However, matched data isn't removed from my table. Anyone have any idea? Thank you very much.

Comment: what do you mean by not matched data? you mean you're expecting to delete a data that have an id of 1?
and if does then check if your code does execute.

Comment: example: ```$this->Posts->deleteAll(['user_id' => 1]); ``` This delete all Post where is user_id 1

Comment: Any chance that this is happening inside a transaction that you don't commit? Or the delete causes some database constraint to be violated (e.g. there's a reference to the to-be-deleted record that prevents it from happening)? Or you're accidentally referencing the wrong table? The code as it's shown looks like it should work.

Comment: Thank you for answering! To be honest, I'm really ashamed of my mistake. My projects using soft delete and I didn't realize it. That's why data wasn't removed. Thank you very much again!